# Cleaning Milanese Loop band for Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, macos

The Milanese Loop band for Apple Watch has the tendency to show some dirt after a few months of regular use. How do you remove this grime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll expand on Apple's [sparse support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204522).

1. Remove the band from Watch.
2. Take a clean cloth (I used a microfiber cloth) and dampen it with water.
3. Wipe down the band, stroking it gently and repeatedly.
4. Turn the band over to the other side and repeat step 3.

The grime should be gone from your band and deposited upon your cloth, as illustrated below.

[image: clean Milanese Loop band with dirty cloth]

Comment: Since the band is stainless steel, you can also use a toothbrush or solvent that's more aggressive than you might use on the watch body itself. It has rubber seals (similar to how you'd protect the black non-metal pieces in the two ends that fit in the watch body) that you'll want to only clean with water.